# How to get an text list of login names for a user group of a windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, user-management

I must copy all login names of a specific user group of a windows server to a 3rd party system. To make it easy I need an text list of the login names. I don't like to copy the login names from the user property dialog and build the list by my own.

I think (and hope) their must be a tool on windows server 2003 R2 to do this task.

Thanks in advance

**My solution**

After hints of duenni I build this batch file which do the job:

```
@echo off
dsget group "CN=MyUserGroup,OU=MyOU3,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU1,DC=MyDC3,DC=MyDC2,DC=MyDC1" -members >users.txt
echo >usernames.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (users.txt) do dsquery * %%i  -attr sAMAccountName >>usernames.txt
find /V "sAMAccountName" usernames.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the MMC "Active Directory Users and Computers" right Click on the OU you want to export goto Action - Export list.

Comment: Thanks, on this way I get a list of all user groups in an organization unit but not a list of all users in a user group. Do you have any further hints?

Comment: Ah, ok, members of a specific group. I overlooked this. I don't think you can solve this with the export feature of the MMC. Have a look at `dsget` and `dsquery` on the commandline. I think it is possible with this command.

Comment: Also found this: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4dbefb7a-6fe6-4779-bbd6-a3210ae72a6d

Comment: Thanks your information lead me to a solution see my updated question. But I accept your answer because it was the needed hint for me